# draw hexagonal like shape SVG

Tags: html, svg

I need to draw svg like below for my project ,

as you see it is like hexagonal but **arms** length are different

and also **angles** are diffrent

[image]

for beginning I have this shape that I made it online

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:bx="https://boxy-svg.com">
  <path d="M 666.103 405.572 Q 674 401.012 681.897 405.572 L 764.819 453.446 Q 772.717 458.006 772.717 467.125 L 772.717 562.875 Q 772.717 571.994 764.819 576.554 L 681.897 624.428 Q 674 628.988 666.103 624.428 L 583.181 576.554 Q 575.283 571.994 575.283 562.875 L 575.283 467.125 Q 575.283 458.006 583.181 453.446 Z" style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 0px;" transform="matrix(0.000073, 1, -1, 0.000073, 770.866394, -503.854004)" bx:shape="n-gon 674 515 113.988 113.988 6 0.08 1@c1c50f7e"/>
</svg>
```

How can I change it to first picture ?

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as inkscape to draw whatever you want.

Comment: Copy the d-path into https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor

Comment: i didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time for it, it can be constructed. Here I create a mask that has the right shape and – in the mask – cut off the corners. This mask is then used on a `<rect>`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 70" width="300">
  <defs>
    <path id="corner" d="M -1 -2 L 6 0 Q 0 0 -3 5.2 Z" />
    <mask id="hex">
      <path d="M 0 34.64 L 20 0 L 100 0 L 120 34.64 L 100 69.28 L 20 69.28 Z" fill="white"/>
      <g fill="black">
        <use transform="translate(20 0)" href="#corner" />
        <use transform="translate(0 34.64) rotate(-60)" href="#corner" />
        <use transform="translate(20 69.28) rotate(-120)" href="#corner" />
        <use transform="translate(100 69.28) rotate(-180)" href="#corner" />
        <use transform="translate(120 34.64) rotate(-240)" href="#corner" />
        <use transform="translate(100 0) rotate(-300)" href="#corner" />
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="120" height="70" fill="#42aaab" mask="url(#hex)" />
</svg>
```